# What would be the mathematical equivalent of this excel formula? =PERCENTRANK()

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to create a SIMS (School Information Management System) assessment sheet that does the same calculation as this Excel =PERCENTRANK() function.

Its full components in Excel are:

```
=PERCENTRANK(Array,X,[Significance])
```

An example Array could be

```
- 13,17,27,33,42,56,61,69,74,83,95,98
```

I am looking to find the percentage rank of each of the values in that array (x)

The significance does not matter as much, as 4-6 decimal places would be handy to sort values that are close to each other out in a larger array.

What would be the equation for this function? I've tried to look up this function but cannot find the math's behind it.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand.

If the Value is present in array, then:

```
Count1 = count of values in Array below than a Value
Count2 = count of values in Array above than a Value
PercentRank = Count1 / (Count1 + Count2)
```

If the Value is not present in array, then its PercentRank is interpolated by PercentRank values of its "neighbors" in array:

```
PercentRank1 = PercentRank of the minimal value Value1 in Array not less than a Value
PercentRank2 = PercentRank of the maximal value Value2 in Array not greater than a Value
PercentRank = (PercentRank1 * (Value1 - Value) + PercentRank2 * (Value - Value2)) / (Value1 - Value2)
```

Comment: You are almost right. This algorithm works differently when value is duplicated. Your description is the same as in docs however I tested this implementation and second count should have formula 'count of values in Array above or equal than a Value minus one'. Then result is the same as in excel.

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late I presume, but we ran into this as well, and looks like the formula is as follows

```
PercentRank.INC = (numOfObservations < targetValue ) / (totalObservations - 1)

PercentRank.EXC = ((numOfObservations < targetValue ) + 1 ) / (totalObservations + 1)
```

Have tested this in an excel sheet, and the results returned matched.